# CakePHP - Plugin does not recognise webroot foler

Tags: cakephp

I'm having a problem with my CakePHP App, I've built a custom plugin, but it is not recognising the Webroot folder within the plugin directory.

In my Controller I have the following:

```
    $css[] = '/pluginname/css/cssfilename';
    $this->set('css_for_layout', $css);

    $js[] = '/pluginname/js/jsfilename';
    $this->set('js_for_layout', $js);
```

As a work around I've just placed the css/js files in the project webroot folder.

I'm running CakePHP 2.2.4

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you post how do you add the css on your view/layout;

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how it should be

```
$this->Html->css(
    array('Pluginname.cssfilename'),
    array('inline' => false)
);
```